# Scala: lazily composing iterators

Tags: scala, iterator

Suppose I have a spreadsheet object that consists of a row Iterator and each row is itself an iterator over cells. I want to create a function that takes the spreadsheet iterator and returns an iterator over Cells.

The simplest version of this is something like:

```
val sheet: Iterable[Row] = //some way of getting the sheet.

case class SheetCell(rowIndex: Int, colIndex: Int, value: Any)

val itr = Iterator(sheet map {row: Row =>
  row map {cell: Cell => SheetCell(row.getRowNum, cell.getColumnIndex, cell)}
})
```

However, I also want to do this lazily. I.e. without actually reading the whole spreadsheet into memory or actually traversing the row/cell iterators, and my understanding is that the above code is not lazy. I'm pretty sure it traverses both the row/cell iterators, builds a `List[SheetCell]` object in memory, and then turns that into an iterator - this is bad.

How would I do this in a way that minimizes resource usage? Should I use Views somehow? How would I do that?

More generally, how do I lazily compose iterators?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is lazy, it just doesn't do what you want.

First, `Iterator(x)` doesn't turn x into an Iterator, it creates a single-element Iterator with x as its only item. `x.toIterator` turns x into an Iterator.

Second, you don't need to do that, as `Iterator.map` already works lazily and returns an Iterator ([doc](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/Iterator.html#map[B](f:A=>B):Iterator[B])).

Lastly, if you want to flatten to a single Iterator, use flatMap instead:

```
sheet.flatMap { row =>
  row.map { cell => SheetCell(row.getRowNum, cell.getColumnIndex, cell) }
}
```

Or, with a for comprehension:

```
for (row <- sheet; cell <- row) yield
  SheetCell(row.getRowNum, cell.getColumnIndex, cell)
```

If you only wanted an `Iterator[Cell]`, you could just do `sheet.flatten`.